# Trouble with revealing and hiding "Slide-Out" Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I am trying to make a slide-out navigation (like in the facebook app).
The navigation is in div with a class of '.menu' and the content is in a '.main' div. I am using jQuery to do it and have the following code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#open').click(function() {
        $('.menu').animate({
            left:"0"
        });
        $('.menu').addClass('active');
        $('.menu').removeClass('inActive');
        $('.main').animate({
            marginLeft:'+=400px'
        });
    });

    if ($('.menu').hasClass('active')) {
        $('#open').click(function() {
            $('.menu').animate({
                left:"-400px"
            });
        });

        $('.menu').addClass('inActive');
        $('.menu').removeClass('active');

    }
```

});

The menu slides out just fine, but I have trouble with hiding it. When revealed, it's class changes from 'active' to 'inActive', so I can check with an if statement whether or not it is shown.

Thanks in advance,
Georgi

Answer (score 1):

You are placing two listeners, one to hide and another to unhide to the same element, you should have a single listener and the condition inside. Something like this:

```
$('#open').click(function() {
    if ($('.menu').hasClass('active')) {
        //Hide it.
    } else {
       //Show it.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why this code block is inside document.ready?

```
if ($('.menu').hasClass('active')) {
...
}
```

The above code block only run one time when the document ready

You should have event listener like , onclick action for the #open , and check the status (active/ inactive) in the listener handler